# Button with image for SwiftUI 2

Tags: swiftui

I want to add button with image inside of the view like twitter button with image for SwiftUI 2, but it is not padding to any directions.

[image]

```
struct WeatherView: View {
var body: some View {
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing:0){
        
        Button(action: {}) {
                        Image("cloud")
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .shadow(radius: 8)
                    }
    
    HStack(spacing: 5){
        
        Text("Rainy")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .fontWeight(.medium)
        
        Spacer()
        
        Button(action: {
            
        }) {
            
            Image("menu").resizable().frame(width: 24, height: 24)
        }
        
    }
    .foregroundColor(Color("black"))
    .padding()
    Spacer()
   
}

}
}
```

Is there any solution for this problem.

Comment: Is there an image/example of what you want? It's unclear the padding you want and for which button.

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are doing well.

This code should do the trick.

```
VStack {
    Spacer()
    Button(action: {}) {
        Image(systemName: "cloud.fill")
            .padding()
            .background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .shadow(radius: 8)
    }
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
.padding()
```

By putting the button in a VStack, and putting a spacer before it, you will push the button to the bottom of the screen. Then by putting a frame on it, and making the width to be .infinity, and giving it alignment trailing, you will further push the button to the trailing side of the screen, which in this case results in making the button at the bottom right corner.

[image]

### Edit: Included full code

```
struct WeatherView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            HStack(spacing: 5) {
                Text("Rainy")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image("menu").resizable().frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                }
                
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color("black"))
            .padding()
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image("cloud")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .shadow(radius: 8)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can further modify the sizing and the padding to achieve the desired result 

Comment: thanks so much for your answer, but it is move with navigation menu.

Comment: Hey! I got it to work on my side, I will edit my post to include the full code right now .

Comment: sorry, I understand now.